# Journey Builder related DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We use a sendable DE "whitepaperdownloads" to store contact data + an whitepaperID of requested whitepapers (will be filled through API) the WhitepaperID is mapped to the "Whitepapers" DE which hold additional information about the whitepaper itself.

We now want to send a Journey and split the journey by the topic of the whitepaper. When using Journey Builder I can only select data from the Journey event (Whitepaperdownloads DE) How to access related DE data in Journey builder when the relation is 1:n (One user, multiple downloads)?

Comment: Is your topic of your white paper in the DE ? If not you would need to bind the DE with the topics to the contact model in contact builder

Comment: Topic is stored in Whitepaper DE which is bind through WhitepaperID on WhitepaperDownload DE (DE's are already bind)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the Whitepaper DE and Whitepapaerdownloads DE in Contact Data Model and then you can access both of these inside Journey Builder for splitting. Make sure you have one to many relationship between both of these DEs